# Chatbot with implementation of list of options using Watson assistant

Tags: entity, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am creating a bot with several intents and entities with watson assistant. The flow of chatbot is depicted in the picture below for understanding better:

[image]

Here,

Q is initial greetings along with four options such as "a","b","c" and "d". If the user selects "a" option, then it enters into the specific "a" branch and "a1" is the first level of question which is posed for the user, if it's answered, then bot should jump to "a2", if it's answered, then jumping should happen to "a3". Likewise, this should happen till "a5".

Same thing should happen with "b".

"c" and "d" have only one question to ask to the user. So, that should be no problem.

Here, in "a2" and "b2", I am trying to display more options like "a21", "a22", "a23", "a24", etc. If the user wants to select more options like we do with the "checkbox" in forms, how should we implement this inside the chatbots?

Can I know, how I should implement this structure? Means where I should deploy the node and slot functionality and other things, to be precise. Any suggestions would be helpful.

I have created the dialog with "Q" as the parent node and "a", "b", "c", "d" as the child nodes. Then I tried creating "a1", "a2","a3","a4" as the slots in "a" node. But, I kinda lost the path in implementing the "a2" with 6 or 7 options. The user should be able to select 2 or more options or even all at sometimes.

Comment: Ask a separate question for each question, i.e., for your intent-related question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend starting with this [guidance on how to design the dialog](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-build.html#dialog-build). Each follow-up interaction to a question should be a child node. Basically, you build a dialog tree similar to what you sketched out on the board.

In each node and depending on the answer you can follow up. This could include jumping to a child node, requesting more information (e.g. via slots), or going back to the start (root node). You can also enable [digression handling](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-runtime.html#digressions) to stay within your tree but react to unplanned or unrelated responses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can we able to make the user select two or more options by displaying some 6 to 7 options? If that so, how should I proceed further? All the options comes under one question alone, over here!

Comment: Something like this? https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-overview.html#multimedia Aside from that you can provide the options as part of the regular text.

Comment: You probably need to take a step back and determine if this is even good for a conversation. A slot with 24 entities can certainly work, but can be very annoying for the end user. Displaying a form with selections might be easier for the user.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty Even I was thinking about that.

Comment: A form is much simpler indeed. Using a dialog you could use natural language and would be able to capture all at once - with the right postprocessing in the place..

Comment: @data_henrik can you direct me to some resources for applying this technique? I was even thinking to ask the user with flow of questions which has to have either "yes" or "no" as the answer. If the user says "yes", I would take that option into account if not, I would leave that. You think, it would work out?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Natural language = Watson Assistant. Take a look at slots of a way to look for several values at once.